# Data augmentation in test/validation set?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

It is common practice to augment data (add samples programmatically, such as random crops, etc. in the case of a dataset consisting of images) on both training and test set, or just the training data set?

Comment: Just training. Golden Rule - Never touch test set. Reason - Test set represents unseen data when you put your model in production.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564146/does-it-make-sense-to-use-data-augmentation-on-the-validation-set-note-this-i?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320800/data-augmentation-on-training-set-only

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Only on training. Data augmentation is used to increase the size of the training set and to get more different images.
Technically, you could use data augmentation on the test set to see how the model behaves on such images, but usually, people don't do it.

Comment: Any reason why the test set or validation set is not augmented?

Comment: In fact situation has changed a bit... There is a new method: test time augmentation. It means augmentation of test data could be used to improve predictions for cases when the object in image is too small. Here is an article with explanation: https://towardsdatascience.com/augmentation-for-image-classification-24ffcbc38833

Comment: How valid is the approach of test-time augmentation @AndreyLukyanenko

Comment: It is valid and commonly used

Answer (score 7):

Data augmentation is done only on training set as it helps the model become more generalize and robust. So there's no point of augmenting the test set.

Answer (score 7):

I would argue that, in some cases, using data augmentation for the *validation* set can be helpful.

For example, I train a lot of CNNs for medical image segmentation. Many of [the augmentation transforms that I use](https://torchio.readthedocs.io/transforms/augmentation.html) are meant to reduce the image quality so that the network is trained to be robust against such data. If the training set looks bad and the validation set looks nice, it will be hard to compare the losses during training and therefore assessing overfit will be complicated.

I would never use augmentation for the test set unless I'm using test-time augmentation to improve results or [estimate aleatoric uncertainty](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231219301961).

Comment: When thinking about problems theoretically often we assume that our training/validation/test sets are drawn from the target distribution, but in practice this is rarely true.  It's often the case that the data on which predictions are *actually* made is pulled from a different dataset than the train/val/test data.  (You can never step into the same river twice and all....)  Augmenting val/test data allows a more realistic estimate for time-of-use performance with well crafted augmentations.  In practice I find using milder augmentations for val/test to best estimate time-of-use performance.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer on stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320967/162527) makes the case for applying crops on the validation / test sets so as to make that input similar the the input in the training set that the network was trained on.

Answer (score 5):

Do it only on the training set. And, of course, make sure that the augmentation does not make the label wrong (e.g. when rotating 6 and 9 by about 180°).

The reason why we use a training and a test set in the first place is that we want to estimate the error our system will have in reality. So the data for the test set should be as close to real data as possible.

If you do it on the test set, you might have the problem that you introduce errors. For example, say you want to recognize digits and you augment by rotating. Then a `6` might look like a `9`. But not all examples are that easy. Better be save than sorry.

Comment: That's not a correct example. If you perform ~=180 degree rotation transforms on digits you're introducing labeling errors also in the training set: you rotate the 6 so now it looks like a 9 but your label continues to be '6' and you feed the network with a sample in the wrong class. That has nothing to do with performing augmentation on the test set.

Answer (score 4):

In computer vision, you can use data augmentation during test time to **obtain different views on the test image**. You then have to aggregate the results obtained from each image for example by averaging them.

For example, given this symbol below, changing the point of view can lead to different interpretations :

[image: different view]

Comment: That can apply to train set too, you know?

Comment: Yes, and doing it only on the train set is much more frequent

Answer (score 2):

Some image preprocessing software tools like Roboflow (https://roboflow.com/) apply data augmentation to test data as well. I'd say that if one is dealing with small and rare objects, say, cerebral microbleeds (which are tiny and difficult to spot on magnetic resonance images), augmenting one's test set could be useful. Then you can verify that your model has learned to detect these objects given different orientation and brightness conditions (given that your training data has been augmented in the same way).

Answer (score 1):

The goal of data augmentation is to generalize the model and make it learn more orientation of the images, such that the during testing the model is able to apprehend the test data well. So, it is well practiced to use augmentation technique only for training sets.

Answer (score 1):

The point of adding validation data is to build generalized model so it is nothing but to predict real-world data. inorder to predict real-world data, the validation set should contain real data. There is no problem with augmenting validation data but it won't increase the accuracy of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents:

You train your model on *the training data **and** the validation data*: the former to optimize your parameters, and the latter to give you an *appropriate* stopping condition. The test data is to give you a real-world estimate of how well you can expect your model to perform.

For training, you can **augment your training data** to increase robustness to various factors including, but not limited to, sampling error, bias between data sources, shifts in global data distribution, positioning, and any other sort of variation you would like to account for.

The validation data should indicate to the training method when the model is most generalizable. By this logic, *if you expect to see some variation* in real-world data that *can be simulated using data augmentation*, then by all means, the **validation dataset should be augmented**.

The **test data**, on the other hand, **should not be augmented**, except potentially in special scenarios where data is very limited, and an estimate of real-world performance on test data has too much variance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use augmentation data in training, validation and test sets.

The only thing to avoid is using the same data from the training set in validation or test sets.

For example, if you generate 3 augmented instances from an register of the training data, make sure that no one of these 3 augmented instances accidentally ends up in the validation or test sets.

It turns out that using data from the training set, even augmented data, to validate or test a model is a methodology mistake.

Comment: Can you elaborate why is this a problem?